# ¿Por qué la expresión indice[arreglo] es equivalente a arreglo[indice]?

Tags: c++, array

Hoy encontré una pieza de código en donde el programa parece tener un error, pero funciona como se espera:

Esta es una simplificación de ese código, que reproduce el mismo comportamiento:

```
int main()
{
  int arreglo[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
  int indice = 0;
  std::cout << arreglo[indice] << "\n";
  indice++;
  std::cout << arreglo[indice] << "\n";
  indice++;
  std::cout << indice[arreglo] << "\n";
  indice++;
  std::cout << arreglo[indice] << "\n";
}
```

Salida:

```
$ ./prueba
0
1
2
3
```

La pregunta es: ¿Por qué funciona la expresión `indice[arreglo]` como si estuviera poniendo `arreglo[indice]`, si deberían estar al revés?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Según la [sección 5.2.1 Subscripting](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) de este working draft del estándar de C++ (Al parecer las especificaciones son vendidas por la ISO y no están públicamente disponibles) se define a `E1[E2]` como

```cpp
E1[E2] == *((E1)+(E2))
```

donde E1 y E2 son cualquier expresión

Entonces

```cpp
arreglo[indice] == *((arreglo) + (indice))
```

Por lo tanto `indice[arreglo]` será equivalente a:

```cpp
indice[arreglo] == *((indice) + (arreglo))
```

Por simple propiedad commutativa de la suma podemos ver que ambas expresiones dan lo mismo

En este caso `arreglo` según la [sección 4.2 Array-to-pointer conversion](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) se convierte implícitamente a la dirección de memoria del primer elemento del arreglo.

Comment: C++ es un estándar ISO que (que yo sepa), siempre son de pago. Sin embargo, los drafts suelen ser iguales a los estándares ISO: cuándo el comité de desarrollo del estándar decide que el draft ya es definitivo, se envía al organismo propiamente dicho --ni idea de a quién concretamente, la verdad, que se supone que lo revisan, y podrían cambiar contenido, pero los drafts son casi universalmente utilizados como equivalentes al estándar, así que asumo que ISO realmente no realiza cambios al estándar para su publicación oficial.

Comment: Como curiosidad, también podrías hacer algo como `-1[p]` para ir al elemento anterior a `p`.

Answer (score 11):

En C++ no existen realmente las matrices como tipo de datos independiente: la sintaxis de matriz no es más que una forma fácil de manipular punteros.

Más concretamente, `matriz[indice]` es en realidad una forma más legible de `*(matriz+indice)`. De ahí que, dado que la suma es conmutativa, obtengas el mismo resultado con `indice[matriz]`, o lo que es lo mismo `*(indice + matriz)`.

Comment: `En C++ no existen realmente las matrices como tipo de datos independiente` No, no es así; una "matriz" (array en el lenguage del estándar C++) es realmente un tipo, es un "compound type", un tipo compuesto. Lo que ocurre es que el nombre de un array se dice que "decae" en puntero (ante la menor provocación, como suele decirse) por ejemplo, si se pasa como argumento de llamada a una función.  Puedes consultar el estándar, por supuesto (6.9.2 Compound types) y también preguntarle a tu compilador; por ejemplo: int arr[5];
    std::cout << typeid(arr).name() << '\n';

Answer (score 8):

C y C++ maneja los arreglos como un puntero a la primera posición del mismo en memoria, luego se accede por medio del índice para acceder a cada posición.

Dicho esto, se da que el compilador convierte esto:

```
indice[arreglo]
```

En esto:

```
*(indice + arreglo)
```

Con la sintaxys normal se convertiría

```
arreglo[indice]
```

en esto:

```
*(arreglo + indice)
```

y por lo tanto ambas expresiones son equivalentes y obtienen el mismo valor. Esto se aplica también para C.

> Extraido del post de [**Martin Geisler**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/110204/martin-geisler). [Ver aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/905737/1913893)

Answer (score 3):

Como has podido leer en otras respuestas `E1[E2] == *((E1)+(E2))`

**Pero no siempre es así.**

Cuando un operador está sobrecargado obedece las reglas sintácticas del operador, pero los requisitos de tipo de operando, categoría de valor y orden de evaluación se reemplazan por las reglas de una invocación de función, como indica la [Nota 2 del capítulo 5 del standard](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) :

> 2 [Note: Operators can be overloaded, that is, given meaning when
>   applied to expressions of class type (Clause 9) or enumeration type
>   (7.2). Uses of overloaded operators are transformed into function
>   calls as described in
>    13.5.  Overloaded operators obey the rules for syntax specified in Clause  5, but the requirements of operand type, value category, and
>   evaluation order are replaced by the rules for function call.
>   Relations between operators, such as ++a meaning a+=1, are not
>   guaranteed for overloaded operators (13.5), and are not guaranteed for
>   operands of type bool. —end note ]

Esto es fácil de comprobar con el siguiente programa :

```
#include<vector>
#include<stdlib.h>

class MiVector
{
public:
    MiVector(size_t s):v(s) {};
    int& operator[](size_t i) { return v[i]; };

private:
    std::vector<int> v;
};

int main()
{
    int vecA[10];
    // Las siguientes dos líneas son equivalentes.
    vecA[3] = 5;
    3[vecA] = 5;

    MiVector vecB(10);
    // Las siguientes dos líneas no son equivalentes.
    vecB[3] = 5;
//    3[vecB] = 5;  // Esta línea da un error de compilación
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`indice[arreglo]` es el azúcar sintáctico de `*(indice+arreglo)`, sabiendo eso y como `(x + y)` es conmutativo usted podría hacerlo también así `*(arreglo+indice)` y obtener el mismo resultado.

```
  int main()
  {
  int arreglo[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
  int indice = 0;
  std::cout << arreglo[indice] << "\n";
  indice++;
  std::cout << arreglo[indice] << "\n";
  indice++;

  std::cout << indice[arreglo] << "\n";
  std::cout << *(indice+arreglo) << "\n";
  std::cout << *(arreglo+indice) << "\n";

  indice++;
  std::cout << arreglo[indice] << "\n";
  }
```

Shell:

```
$ ./prueba
0
1
2
2
2
3
```

Answer (score -1):

Ya que se reavivó el tema, aprovecho para decir que creo que están muy bien las explicaciones que aclaran el por qué de `array[indice] == indice[array]`, cuando eso es cierto; bueno, que estoy de acuerdo con casi todas las respuestas.

Pero faltaría añadir que esa igualdad siempre es válida en C pero no siempre en C++; de hecho muchas veces la expresión `indice[array]` no tiene sentido, no es una expresión válida (y afortunadamente tampoco compila).

La diferencia está en que en C++ la expresión `E1[E2] == *((E1)+(E2))` tiene una condición adicional:

**Estándar C++ [8.2.1 Subscripting]**

> One of the expressions shall be a glvalue of type “array of T ” or a
>   prvalue of type “pointer to T ” and the other shall be a prvalue of
>   unscoped enumeration or integral type.

En expresiones compatibles con el C no hay problema, porque siempre una de estas `E`xpresiones es siempre un puntero a `T` (o decae en puntero a T), pero no necesariamente es siempre así.

Ejemplo. Acá, sobrecargando el operador [] se le da significado a `terna[indice]`, pero no es posible hacer `indice[terna]`:

```
struct Mi_terna {
    int& operator[](int i) { return n[i]; }
    int n[3];
};

int main()
{
     Mi_terna terna { 1, 2, 3 };
     int indice = 0;

     terna[indice] = 9;  // bien, invoca Mi_terna::operator[](int)
     indice[terna] = 9;  // mal, no hay int::operator[](Mi_terna) 
}
```