# ¿Cómo asignar un arreglo retornado por una funcion a un arreglo del programa principal?

Tags: c, punteros, array

Lo que quiero hacer es asignar el arreglo que cree en la funcion a un arreglo del programa principal. Busque en internet y me aparecio que se resolvia de la forma que estoy mostrando el codigo pero cuando lo ejecuto me marca error.

Quisiera saber como es la forma correcta o si es esta y yo lo estoy haciendo mal. Gracias!

El error que me marca es este:

> ```
> invalid conversion from `int*' to `int'
> ```

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int * iniciararreglo();

int main()
{
    int a[100];
    *a=iniciararreglo();    

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

int * iniciararreglo()
{ int num,arreglo[100];
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i=0;i<=99;i++)
    { num=0+ rand()%(100);
        arreglo[i]=num; }
    return *arreglo; }
```

Comment: Se podría Ayudar más si pusieras el error que te está marcando el programa

Comment: ¿Por qué añadiste el `using namespace std`? Si el código es C (a juzgar por las cabeceras usadas) y el compilador usado es de C, no debería ser una instrucción aceptada ya que C no dispone de espacios de nombres.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster También está la librería `cstdlib`. Está compilando en C++ aunque lo mismo no es consciente de ello

Comment: Creo que *reutiliza* un archivo con los `#include< >` y el `using ...` para probar código en C, compilandolo con un compilador C++, sin percatarse de ello ... hasta que tropiece con alguna *incompatibilidad`, claro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error que te aparece se debe a que estas tratando de asignar un valor `int*` (puntero), a una variable `[]` (arreglo). Por lo tanto el compilador te indica este error.

**Solucion**

En lugar de hacer que la funcion `iniciararreglo()` retorne un elemento `int` haremos que en su lugar no retorne nada, mas como argumento le pasaremos el arreglo en el cual se insertaran todos los numeros.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

void iniciararreglo(int arreglo[100]);

int main() {

    int a[100];
    iniciararreglo(a);

    // Imprimimos el arreglo
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        cout << a[i] << endl;
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void iniciararreglo(int arreglo[100]) {

    int num;
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i <= 99; i++) {
        num = 0 + rand() % (100);
        arreglo[i] = num;
    }

    return;
}
```

**Resultado:**

```
66
9
1
84
80
52
7
26
75
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Un arreglo es una colección de elementos del mismo tipo que están almacenados de manera anexa en memoria; por lo tanto para definir un arreglo necesitamos su tipo y su tamaño... por ejemplo en tú código tienes:

```
int a[100];
```

Este arreglo es de cien elementos de tipo `int`.

### Detalles técnicos.

Tanto en C como en C++ el nombre de un arreglo equivale a un puntero a la primera posición del mismo; se pueden usar diferentes operadores sobre un puntero para acceder a diferentes datos, por ejemplo:

#### Operador corchetes `[]`.

El operador corchetes te permite indicar un desplazamiento respecto al inicio de un arreglo, siguiendo tu arreglo de ejemplo poniendo un cero (`0`) entre corchetes al lado del arreglo `a` accederíamos al **a la primera posición**:

```
a[0] = 42;
```

Si en lugar de un cero pusiéramos un `99` accederíamos a la **centésima posición**:

```
a[99] = 0b101010;
```

Esto funciona así por una característica conocida como "*aritmética de punteros*", que a grandes rasgos significa que sumando un valor a un puntero devuelve un nuevo puntero apuntando a la dirección de memoria del puntero original desplazado tantas veces como el valor multiplicado por el tamaño del tipo apuntado. Puedes ver más detalles en [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/803/por-qu%c3%a9-la-expresi%c3%b3n-indicearreglo-es-equivalente-a-arregloindice).

#### Operador de des-referencia `*`.

El operador de des-referencia aplicado sobre un puntero devuelve el dato apuntado, por lo tanto si tenemos un puntero a entero (`int *`) y lo des-referenciamos, obtenemos un entero (`int`).

### Problema.

En tu código usas las siguientes instrucciones:

```
int a[100];
*a=iniciararreglo();
```

```
int * iniciararreglo()
{ int num,arreglo[100];
// ...
    return *arreglo; }
```

Como acabamos de leer, las instrucciones `*a` y `*arreglo` están des-referenciando un puntero (el nombre de un arreglo es un puntero al primer elemento del arreglo). Por lo tanto el tipo de las instrucciones `*a` y `*arreglo` es `int`. La función `iniciararreglo()` devuelve un valor de tipo `int *` tal y como puede verse en su declaración:

```
int * iniciararreglo();
```

Dado que `int` e `int *` son tipos incompatibles, se te muestra el error que describes:

> ```
> invalid conversion from `int*' to `int'
> ```

### Diseño de función `iniciararreglo()`.

Por lo que puedo ver en tu función, estás devolviendo un arreglo interno de la función:

```
int * iniciararreglo()
{ int num,arreglo[100];
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i=0;i<=99;i++)
    { num=0+ rand()%(100);
        arreglo[i]=num; }
    return *arreglo; }
```

El arreglo `arreglo` pertenece al contexto de la función `iniciararreglo` y **deja de existir cuando finaliza la función**, así que tras la instrucción `return *arreglo;` devolvería memoria que deja de existir en el mismo momento que se hace el `return`.

### Propuesta.

La función `iniciararreglo()` no debería devolver ningún dato si no que debería recibir un puntero y un tamaño:

```
void iniciararreglo(int *puntero, int elementos)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < elementos; ++i)
    {
        puntero[i] = rand() % 100;
    }
}
```

Sería usada así:

```
int main()
{
    int a[100];
    iniciararreglo(a, 100);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: probe la solucion que me has dicho pero me ha dado este error: " void value not ignored as it ought to be"

Comment: @MacaIgoillo mil perdones, **es un error mío** la llamada a `iniciararreglo` debe ser así: `iniciararreglo(a, 100);` (sin poner `*a` a la izquierda). Corrijo la respuesta.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster, no te molestes. Ya usó mi código para su siguiente pregunta http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/46340/porque-no-se-me-ordena-el-array-correctamente-en-c Ni acepta, ni upvote, ni *n'a de n'a*