# Porque no se me ordena el array correctamente en c?

Tags: c

Cuando ejecuto el programa me muestra el array creado correctamente, pero el problema es que no me lo ordena. 
No se si sera un problema de como paso el arreglo como parametro a las funciones, ya que estoy aprendiendo y todavia me cuesta un poco ese tema. Muchas gracias

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int *generarArreglo(int size);
void OrdenaMburbujaD (int * a1);
void OrdenaMburbujaA (int * a1);
int main()
{
char op;
int *a;
a=generarArreglo(100);
if (a==NULL)
 { printf("No hya memoria suficiente para el arreglo"); }
else {    

printf("Arreglo sin ordenar \n");
for (int i=0;i<=99;i++)
   { printf("%d   ", a[i]);}
printf ("\n");

printf("Ingrese la letra D para ordenar el arreglo de forma Descendente \n"
       "Ingrese la letra A para ordenar el arreglo de forma Ascendente \n");
op=getchar();

if (op= 'd')
  { OrdenaMburbujaD(a); }
else if (op= 'a') {OrdenaMburbujaA(a);}
printf("Arreglo ordenado \n");
for (int i=0;i<=99;i++)
   { printf("%d   ", a[i]);} }







system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
int *generarArreglo(int size)
{   
int idx;
int *arr;

arr = (int *)calloc( size, sizeof( int ) );

if( arr ) {
srand( time( NULL ) ); }

for( idx = 0; idx < size; ++idx )
  {arr[idx] = rand( ) % 100;} 
  return arr; }

  void OrdenaMburbujaD (int * a1)
 {

 int pasada, j,almacena1;
 for (pasada=0;pasada<=99;pasada++)
    {  for(j=0;j<=99;j++)
          { if (a1[j]<a1[j+1])
              { almacena1=a1[j];
                a1[j]=a1[j+1];
                a1[j+1]=almacena1;}}} 
 }

 void OrdenaMburbujaA (int * a1)
{

 int pasada, j, almacena;
 for (pasada=0;pasada<=99;pasada++)
    {  for(j=0;j<=99;j++)
          { if (a1[j]>a1[j+1])
              { almacena=a1[j];
                a1[j]=a1[j+1];
                a1[j+1]=almacena;}}} 
 }
```

Comment: me parece que te falta el & al pasar al momento de llamar a tus metodos de ordenamiento, tambien en el segundo for deberia llegar hasta 98

Comment: ahi cambie lo del segundo for! ahora voy a probar con el &

Comment: Pese a haber respondido, voto para cerrar como **error tipográfico**

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que el error esta en que no estas retornando el arreglo arreglado, intenta con esto

```
 int* OrdenaMburbujaA (int * a1){
   int pasada, j, almacena;
   for (pasada=0;pasada<=99;pasada++)
   {  for(j=0;j<=99;j++)
      { if (a1[j]>a1[j+1])
          { almacena=a1[j];
            a1[j]=a1[j+1];
            a1[j+1]=almacena;}}} 
    return a1;
  }
```

Y luego obviamente

```
if (op= 'd')
  { a = OrdenaMburbujaD(a); }
```

Comment: `if (op= 'd')` --> `if (op == 'd')`

Answer (score 1):

Sigues usando `#include <iostream>`, y luego etiquetas la pregunta como **C**.

Que el código te funcione, indica que estás usando un compilador de C++, lo cual, en algún momento, te llevará a una *incompatibilidad* de difícil diagnóstico. Cambialo por

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

y compila con C, o cambia la etiqueta de **C** a **C++**.

Siguiendo, haces

```
if( op= 'd' ) {
  OrdenaMburbujaD( a );
} else if( op = 'a' ) {
  OrdenaMburbujaA(a);
}
```

Aunque eso es válido, en C y C++ para comparar se utiliza el operador `==`:

```
if( op == 'd' ) {
  OrdenaMburbujaD( a );
} else if( op == 'a' ) {
  OrdenaMburbujaA(a);
}
```

Con esos simples cambios, tu código funciona **perfecto**.

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Luego me di cuenta que el error era simplemente que por error de tipeo puse "=" en vez de "==".

Answer (score 1):

El problema creo que está en las condiciones `if` que comprueban la opción tecleada. No entiendo si tienes otro problema porque yo he compilado el tuyo cambiando las asignaciones `=` por comparaciones `==` dentro de los `if` y me ha funcionado bien.

Por cierto, aquí va tu código arreglado y usando algo más de C++ (he sustituido las librerías de C por las equivalentes de C++):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

int *generarArreglo(int size);
void OrdenaMburbujaD (int * a1);
void OrdenaMburbujaA (int * a1);

int main()
{
  char op;
  int *a;
  a = generarArreglo(100);
  if (a == NULL) {
    std::cout << "No hya memoria suficiente para el arreglo" << std::endl;
  }
  else {    

    std::cout << "Arreglo sin ordenar" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 99; i++) {
      std::cout << a[i] << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Ingrese la letra D para ordenar el arreglo de forma Descendente" << std::endl <<
      "Ingrese la letra A para ordenar el arreglo de forma Ascendente" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> op;
    if (op == 'd') {
      OrdenaMburbujaD(a);
    } else if (op == 'a') {
      OrdenaMburbujaA(a);
    }
    std::cout << "Arreglo ordenado" << std::endl;
    for (int i=0; i <= 99; i++) {
      std::cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
  return 0;
}

int *generarArreglo(int size)
{   
  int idx;
  int *arr;

  arr = (int *)std::calloc(size, sizeof(int));

  if ( arr ) {
    std::srand( std::time( NULL ) ); }

  for( idx = 0; idx < size; ++idx )
  {arr[idx] = std::rand( ) % 100;} 
  return arr; }

void OrdenaMburbujaD (int * a1)
{

  int pasada, j,almacena1;
  for (pasada=0;pasada<=99;pasada++)
  {  for(j=0;j<=99;j++)
    { if (a1[j]<a1[j+1])
      { almacena1=a1[j];
        a1[j]=a1[j+1];
        a1[j+1]=almacena1;}}} 
}

void OrdenaMburbujaA (int * a1)
{

  int pasada, j, almacena;
  for (pasada=0;pasada<=99;pasada++)
  {  for(j=0;j<=99;j++)
    { if (a1[j]>a1[j+1])
      { almacena=a1[j];
        a1[j]=a1[j+1];
        a1[j+1]=almacena;}}} 
}
```

PD: Si no te gusta ir poniendo `std::` puedes agregar en la parte superior `using namespace std;`, pero yo prefiero tener claro siempre a qué espacio de nombres pertenece cada función.

Comment: sii!! luego me di cuenta que era q me falto la igualacion. Por error de tipeo habia puesto "=" en vez de "==". Muchas gracias igualmente

Comment: De nada, un placer. Yo me di cuenta cuando ya llevaba un rato trabajando en arreglar el código :'D suelo hacerlo así para ir entendiendo el código, y al final será una pérdida de tiempo porque se cerrará esta pregunta :'(