# Problemas con los parámetros en arreglos en C

Tags: c++, c, array, funciones

Tengo un problema en un case en main para calcular los promedios de tres alumnos mediante el uso de arreglos y funciones. El problema en la consola se lee como `error C2664: 'PromAlumnos' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'float' to 'float []'`, aunque sinceramente no logro detectar el problema con los tamaños dados y obtenidos en la función. Este es el case dentro de main:

```
case 4:  
for ( indice = 0; indice < ICAP; indice++ )
{
    fpromA[ indice ] = PromAlumnos(fmate[ indice ], fhist[ indice ], fcomp[ indice ]);
}
break;
```

Y esta es la función:

```
float PromAlumnos ( float fmat[], float fhis[], float fcom[] )
{
    int index = 0;
    float tama = 3.0;
    float promAlum = 0.0;
    float califAlumnos[1];
    califAlumnos[ index ] = fmat[ index ] + fhis[ index ] + fcom[ index ];
    promAlum = califAlumnos[ index ]/tama;
    return promAlum;
}
```

El error se muestra en la línea cuatro del case. Muchas gracias por su ayuda!

Comment: Parece ser que tu error está en la forma en la que pasas los parámetros a la función `PromAlumnos` la cual espera 3 argumentos que son arrays de tipo `float` pero le estás enviando valores de tipo float que no son arrays. Provee información sobre que hay dentro de `fmate`, `fhist` y `fcomp` para ofrecerte una respuesta completa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando llamas a la función, haces

```
fpromA[ indice ] = PromAlumnos(fmate[ indice ], fhist[ indice ], fcomp[ indice ]);
```

es decir, la estas llamando pasándole `float` como argumentos.

Sin embargo, el cuerpo de la función lo has declarado como

```
float PromAlumnos ( float fmat[], float fhis[], float fcom[] )
```

ahí, estas esperando *arreglos*, datos de tipo `float[]`. Son tipos distintos.

La solución mas acorde con lo que indicas en la pregunta seria

```
case 4:  
  for ( indice = 0; indice < ICAP; indice++ ) {
    fpromA[ indice ] = PromAlumnos( fmate, fhist, fcomp, indice );
    //                                                   ^ añadido
  }
  break;
```

dentro del `switch( )`, y cambiar tu función así

```
float PromAlumnos ( float fmat[], float fhis[], float fcom[], int index )
{
  // int index = 0; <- lo recibes como argumento
  float tama = 3.0;
  float promAlum = 0.0;
  float califAlumnos; // <- Sin arreglo.
  califAlumnos = fmat[ index ] + fhis[ index ] + fcom[ index ];
  //          ^ sin arreglo
  promAlum = califAlumnos / tama;
  //                     ^ sin arreglo
  return promAlum;
}
```

o bien, si `califAlumnos` es obligatorio que sea un arreglo

```
float PromAlumnos ( float fmat[], float fhis[], float fcom[], int index )
{
  // int index = 0; <- lo recibes como argumento
  float tama = 3.0;
  float promAlum = 0.0;
  float califAlumnos[1];
  califAlumnos[0] = fmat[ index ] + fhis[ index ] + fcom[ index ];
  promAlum = califAlumnos[0] / tama;
  return promAlum;
}
```

Si estuvieras en el *mundo real*, y no el académico, el código sería mas simple. El `switch( )` seria igual que el que usas actualmente, pero tu función seria:

```
float PromAlumnos ( float fmat, float fhis, float fcom )
{
  // Por defecto, los números en coma flotante son 'double'.
  // Indicamos que usamos 'float'.
  return ( fmat + fhis + fcom ) / 3.0f; // <- literal f. 
}
```

Volviendo a los arreglos, al hacer

```
float arreglo[5];
```

en memoria se generan 5 `float` consecutivos. El tipo de la variable `arreglo` sería `float[5]` si indicas el tamaño, o `float[]` si no lo haces.

En cambio, el tipo de `arreglo[0]` es `float`. No estas usando el *arreglo*, sino uno de sus elementos contenidos.

Es como si etiquetas un cajón con una pegatina que diga `lápices`; el *tipo* del cajón seria `cajón de lápices`, pero cada uno de estos sería simplemente un `lápiz` ( que explicación mas *rara* acabo de hacer :-)

Answer (score 1):

> `error C2664: 'PromAlumnos' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'float' to 'float []'`

El error es bastante auto-explicativo: no se puede convertir el primer parámetro de un tipo de datos a otro, en tu caso de `float` a `float []`.

La función que estás llamando es:

```
float PromAlumnos ( float fmat[], float fhis[], float fcom[], int index )
```

Y su primer parámetro es de tipo `float []`, veamos cómo la estás llamando:

```
fpromA[ indice ] = PromAlumnos(fmate[ indice ], fhist[ indice ], fcomp[ indice ]);
```

**No has incluido en tu pregunta la definición de `fmate`** (ni de las otras variables), así que sólo podemos hacer conjeturas, pero aparentemente `fmate` es un arreglo de objetos `float`, [al usar el operador corchetes (`[]`) estás devolviendo un objeto `float`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/45646/c%c3%b3mo-asignar-un-arreglo-retornado-por-una-funcion-a-un-arreglo-del-programa-pri/45681#45681), así que en el primer parámetro estás pasando un `float` y la función espera un `float []`.

Como veo que internamente la función `PromAlumnos` funciona con `float` en lugar de con arreglos, *seguramente* te funcione adecuadamente así:

```
case 4:  
for ( indice = 0; indice < ICAP; indice++ )
{
    fpromA[ indice ] = PromAlumno(fmate[ indice ], fhist[ indice ], fcomp[ indice ]);
}
break;
```

```
float PromAlumno ( float fmat, float fhis, float fcom )
{
    return (fmat + fhis + fcom) / 3.0;
}
```

Sin ver más código no puedo estar seguro de lo que estás haciendo, pero para hacer la media aritmética de tres valores numéricos no necesitas más.