# ¿Como escribir funciones que permiten la asignación y la liberación de memoria de un arreglo?

Tags: c++, manejo-de-memoria

Estoy aprendiendo como manejar la memoria en c++ y no sé como asignarla y liberarla con funciones para la creación de *arreglos* de una dimensión o dos dimensiones. ¿Pueden ayudarme ? Aquí esta lo que intenté :

```
#include<iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h> 

using namespace std;

int allocationTableau(int *&arregloEnteros, size_t size){
    return new int[size];
}

void remplissageTableau( int arregloEnteros[]){
    cout << "escribe los numeros del arreglo" <<endl;
    for(int i = 0; i<sizeof(arregloEnteros); i++){
        cout << "falta " << sizeof(arregloEnteros) -i << "numeros a escribir" <<endl;
        cin >> arregloEnteros[i];
    }

}


void desallocationTableau(int *arregloEnteros[]){

    delete[] arregloEnteros;

}

int main(){

    int *arregloEnteros;

    allocationTableau(tableauRigolo);
    remplissageTableau(tableauRigolo);
    sommeTableau(tableauRigolo);
    desallocationTableau(tableauRigolo);

    return 0;


}
```

Comment: Por tu anterior pregunta, se de que estás hablando. El resto de los usuarios, no. Edito el título y algo del texto (lo de `tabula` no se entiende en Español). Por favor, si muestras código, que se ajuste a [`Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable`](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Ya llevas tiempo en el sitio.

Comment: Relacionada: [¿Cómo asignar un arreglo retornado por una funcion a un arreglo del programa principal?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/45646/19610). **No** duplicada, porque ésta es C++ y aquella C.

Comment: @Trauma cambiaré los nombres, promesa!

Comment: estoy en el [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53473/conversacion-con-marine1)

Comment: Te agradeceríamos que al editar una pregunta mantuvieses el código original. Si editas el código una vez te han respondido las respuestas pasan a ser obsoletas... ya que no se ajustan al código que contiene la nueva pregunta. (Los comentarios de @Trauma entre `malloc` y `new` no tienen ningún sentido si en tu código no estás haciendo mención alguna a `malloc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de nada:

## ¡ No mezcles `malloc( )` con `delete`, ni `new` con `free( )` !

Espero que el mensaje se *entienda* bien.

El resultado de esas mezclas es **indefinido**.

Aun *sabiendo* que `new` y `delete` realicen *internamente* llamadas a `malloc( )` y `free( )` (cosa que **no sabemos**), el uso de dichas funciones **no llama a los constructores ni a los destructores**. Los operadores **si** lo hacen. Se añadieron al lenguaje para eso.

Piensa que, aunque tú mismo llames a los constructores después del `malloc( )`, las *excepciones* no se gestionaran adecuadamente, por lo que también tendrás que encargarte de llamar a los destructores *a mano* si algún constructor falla. Y te arriesgas a *fugas de memoria*. Aparte de que el formateo de los tipos (*casting*) necesario está *feo*.

#### Y dicho lo anterior ...

Un primer vistazo a tú código no nos aclara mucho ... variables que no sabemos de donde salen ... en fin, imagino que serán cosas del *copy/paste*. Menos mal que el título nos orienta bastante.

#### Creación dinámica de *arreglos*

Crear un *arreglo* dentro de una función, y devolverlo, es sencillo:

```
int *createTabula( size_t size ) {
  return new int[size];
}
```

Como digo, muy simple. El operador `new[]` se encarga de todo: reserva la memoria, devuelve el tipo correcto ..., un *chollo*, vamos. Lo único que necesita es conocer el tipo y el tamaño.

#### Destrucción de *arreglos* creados de forma dinámica

El paso opuesto al anterior es igual de simple:

```
void destroyTabula( int *ptr ) {
  delete[] ptr;
}
```

Como vemos, `delete[]` es aún mas simple de usar. Solo necesita el puntero.

#### Uso

Ahora, un pequeño ejemplo; creo que *similar* a lo que pretende tu código:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int *createTabula( size_t size ) {
  return new int[size];
}

void destroyTabula( int *ptr ) {
  delete[] ptr;
}

void fillTabula( int *ptr, size_t size ) {
  int idx;

  for( idx = 0; idx < size; ++idx ) {
    cout << "falta " << size - idx << "numeros que necesitemos escribir" << endl;
    cin >> ptr[idx];
  }
}

int main( ) {
  int *tabula;
  int tabulaSize = 10;

  tabula = createTabula( tabulaSize );
  fillTabula( tabula, tabulaSize );
  destroyTabula( tabula );

  return 0;
}
```

**EDITO**

No estoy seguro de entender tu comentario. Si lo que pretendes hacer es declarar la variable en una función, y asignar la memoria en otra, pasándola como argumento, es simple también:

1. Pasándola como *puntero a puntero*:

Este método es el único disponible en C; es perfectamente válido en C++. Los punteros pueden apuntar **a cualquier tipo, incluido otro puntero**.

```
void createTabula( int **tab, size_t size ) {
  *tab = new int[size];
}

int main( ) {
  int *tabula;

  createTabula( &tabula );

  return 0;
}
```

Como puedes ver, creamos un puntero normal, y pasamos *su dirección* a la función. `**int` se lee como `un puntero que apunta a un puntero que apunta a un entero`. Un pelín lioso, cierto. C/C++ soportan varios niveles de *indirección* (no se cuantos, en el estándar lo pondrá). Mas que nosotros, seguro ;-)

2. Pasandola por *referencia*:

Esta es la *forma C++ de hacer las cosas*. **No** es válida en C:

```
void createTabula( int *&tbl, size_t size ) {
  tbl = new int[size];
}

int main( ) {
  int *tabula;

  createTabula( tabula );

  return 0;
}
```

Como puedes ver, utilizamos otro tipo: `*&int` se lee como `referencia a un puntero a entero`. Y si, tienes razón, está colocado *al revés*. Pero eso es para otra pregunta distinta ;-)

Comment: Muchas gracias, `malloc( )` no esta `delete`, y `new` no esta `free( )`. ¿Sin embargo, en la creación dinámica de arreglos, si quería crear un arreglo **pasado como parámetro** dentro de una función, y devolverlo, como podría hacerlo ? He traido `return new int tableauEntiers[taille]);`pero no funciona ...

Comment: @Marine1 en `assignacionTabula( )` haces el `malloc( )`.  En `desassignacionTabula( )` llamas a `delete[]`. No hay `free( )` ni `new[]`, y da la impresión de que *intentas hacer* lo que indico. He editado la respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Me queda solo una error (`Violación de acceso`)cuando estoy escrbido en el arreglo por lo momento. 
Quiero declarar la variable en una función, y asignar la memoria en la misma : *"la première fonction alloue a un tableau d’entiers passé en paramètre, la taille étant également passée en paramètre"*
He cambiado el código un poquito.

Comment: Sin embargo como hacer para escribir en el arreglo con `void fillTabula( int *ptr)` pero sin el tamano ?

Comment: La implementación por defecto de `new` __suele__ llamar a `malloc` por simple comodidad (Apache, MSVC y Clang, por poner algunos ejemplos, trabajan así). Si una implementación no llama a `malloc` tiene que currarse la reserva de memoria casi desde cero y eso normalmente no compensa. De hecho si tu sobreescribes la implementación de `new` sueles llamar a `malloc` para hacer la reserva y después ya realizas la llamada al constructor que te interese.