# ¿Por qué me marca error cuándo uso malloc en c?

Tags: c

Tengo el siguiente código, estaba haciendo una prueba para usar malloc, pero cuando pongo una matriz de 5x5 o más grande me dice que el programa dejó de funcionar, sin embargo con matrices más pequeñas todo funciona correctamente.

```
#include <stdio.h>
    #include <malloc.h>

    int **m = NULL;
    int filas = 5;
    int columnas = 2;
    int i,j;

    int main(){
    read();
    addcr();   
    fill();
    imprimir();
        return 0;
    }


    read(){
    printf("Ingrese el número de filas: \n");
        scanf("%d",&filas);
        printf("Ingrese el número de columnas: \n");
        scanf("%d",&columnas);
        printf("Sus valores son filas = %d columnas = %d \n",filas,columnas);
    }

    addcr(){
    m = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int)*filas);
    for(i=0; i < filas; i++) 
    m[ i ]=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*columnas); 

    printf("addcr terminado \n");
    }

    fill(){
        printf("fill iniciado %d , %d \n",filas,columnas);
        int contador=0;
        for(i=0;i<filas;i++){
            for(j=0;j<columnas;j++){
            m[i][j]=contador++;
    //      printf("contador %d \n",contador);  
            //Sleep(3000);


            }   
        }
        printf("fill terminado \n");
    }

    imprimir(){
        printf("imprimir iniciado \n");
    for(i=0;i<filas;i++){
            for(j=0;j<columnas;j++){
            printf("%d \n",m[i][j]);            
            }   
        }

    }
```

Para verificar que funcionara el malloc llené la matriz de números y luego imprimí la matriz, puse **printf()** para saber hasta donde funciona la aplicación antes de detenerse y llega hasta el método **fill()** y nunca lo termina.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que tu estás haciendo es **bastante** mas *enrevesado* de lo necesario. Al hacer

```
int **m = NULL;
```

estás declarando un **puntero a puntero**, que **no es lo que pretendes**.
Luego, haces

```
addcr( ) {
  m = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int)*filas);
  for(i=0; i < filas; i++) 
  m[ i ]=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*columnas); 
}
```

donde en realidad estas creando un arreglo de punteros a arreglos; creo que tampoco es lo que pretendes.

Luego, haces

```
fill( ) {
  printf("fill iniciado %d , %d \n",filas,columnas);
  int contador=0;
  for(i=0;i<filas;i++){
    for(j=0;j<columnas;j++){
      m[i][j]=contador++;
    }   
  }
}
```

con eso, estas sobrepasando las zonas de memoria asignadas por `malloc( )`; estas escribiendo en memoria que *no es tuya*, y posiblemente sea el error que te genera.

Declarar un array de X dimensiones es muy simple:

```
int *m = NULL;
```

con eso es suficiente.

Para reservar memoria:

```
m = (int *)malloc( sizeof( int ) * filas * columnas );
```

La función `addcr( )` **no te hace falta**. Simplemente con los mínimos cambios que te indico, todo debería de funcionar bien.

El *truco* está en como C / C++ manejan los punteros. Una expresión del tipo

```
puntero[indice1]...[indiceX]
```

es interpretada por el compilador como

```
puntero + ( sizeof( TIPO ) * indice1 ) + ... + ( sizeof( TIPO ) * indiceX
```

Ese te permite una *flexibilidad* **absoluta** en como *interpretes* tu bloque de memoria. Por ejemplo, si haces

```
int *ptr = (int *)malloc( sizeof( int ) * 100 );
```

puedes acceder a los elementos de varias formas:

```
*ptr = 0; // es igual que ptr[0] = 0
ptr[26] = 1; // es igual que ptr[24][1] = 1
```

De hecho, **es responsabilidad tuya** el comprobar que *no te sales* del bloque de memoria. El compilador *ignora* por completo la aritmética que uses, y te deja hacer *lo que quieras* con los punteros. Desde el punto de vista del compilador, *allá tú*.

Te sugiero que consultes [¿Por qué la expresión indice[arreglo] es equivalente a arreglo[indice]?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/803/19610) Si bien es sobre C++, es *literalmente* aplicable a C.

**EDITO**

Sobre el porqué te falla dependiendo del tamaño del arreglo, es un tema mas *delicado* y tocamos directamente *las tripas* bajo la superficie.

Las reservas de memoria **no** se realizan con el tamaño exacto, sino que se redondean a ciertos tamaños *mínimos*; tú puedes hacer `malloc( 10 )`, y el sistema puede en realidad reservar un bloque de 100 *bytes*. Eso es transparente para el programador, no afectándonos *para nada*.

El objetivo es acelerar las operaciones y facilitar la reutilización de los bloques (`free( )` y `malloc( )` mezclados, o `realloc( )`).

Por ello, en tu código, mientras lo que intentabas hacer *cabía* en ese bloque *real*, que es mas grande que el tú pedías, no había problemas.

En cuanto *te pasabas* de ese tamaño, tenías el problema indicado: accedías a memoria que *no es tuya*.

Ese *tamaño mínimo de redondeo* es *dependiente* de las librerias, y no tienes forma *portable* de saberlo. Ni te es necesario.