# ¿Cómo imprimir cuatro carácteres de una cadena al mismo tiempo?

Tags: c

Disculpen, ¿cómo puedo imprimir cuatro carácteres al mismo tiempo de una cadena? Ya tengo mi cadena y sé como imprimir un solo carácter pero quiero que imprima cuatro o cinco al mismo tiempo. ¿Alguien puede ayudarme?
Gracias.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char cadena[30]={"Hola mundo soy muy feliz"};
    int salto,coma,i;

    printf("%c",cadena[11]);


    return 0;
}
```

Donde imprime la letra yo quiero que imprima cuatro o cinco o más al mismo tiempo.

Comment: ¿Podrías [edit] la pregunta mostrando el código de cómo estás imprimiendo 1 caracter y aclarando qué te está trayendo problemas?

Comment: ignora las variables que estan declaradas

Comment: no se que paso el pegar el codigo, pero bueno, ahi solo imprimo un caracter yo quiero imprimir mas de uno

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int main()
{
    char cadena[30]={"Hola mundo soy muy feliz"};
    int salto,coma,i;

    //esta podria ser una manera cada uno de los `%c` es sustituido secuencialmente por cadena[11], cadena[15] ect, fijese en que son separados por `,`
    printf("%c - %c - %c - %c", cadena[11], cadena[15], cadena[20], cadena[38]);

    printf("\n---\n");

    //Otra manera en la funcion printf especificar la precision justo antes del caracter de formato %`precision`s -> %.5s, lo siguiente en este caso cadena + 1, es arimetica de punteros para determinar el punto de inicio/comiezo 
    printf("%.5s", cadena + 1);
    printf("\n---\n");
    printf("%.10s", cadena);
    printf("\n---\n");
    printf("%.14s", cadena + 10);

    return 0;
}
```

---

```
printf("%.14s", cadena + 10);
```

Bien `%.14s` o `%.xs`es la precision (los caracteres como maximo que va ha intentar escribir) `cadena + 10` o `cadena + x` es arimetica de punteros para determinar el punto de inicio/comiezo, apartir del cual emperzara a aplicar la precision.

Idea rapida:

si `cadena` es el inicio de la cadena, `cadena + x` es el inicio de la cadena desplazado x

*intentare poner un [link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/803/por-qu%C3%A9-la-expresi%C3%B3n-indicearreglo-es-equivalente-a-arregloindice/809#809) de una respuesta que lo puede ayudar a entender mejor.*

---

Tambien puede especificar la precision mediante una variable y haciendo uso de `*s` en lugar del solo el caracter de formato `s` aqui un ejemplo:

```
//..
int len = 5;
printf("\n---\n");
printf("%.*s", len, cadena + 1);
```

Fijese que `%.5s` visto anteriormente se sustiye por `%.*s` de donde `*` toma su valor de `len` que es uno de los parametros que tiene la funcion, el resto funciona igual que lo anterior.

[`printf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)